# WPF Datagrid Cache

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, datagrid

I've Created a datagrid
and binded an Observable Collection to datagrid ItemsSource.
When clearing the Observable colletion cache memory isn't being cleared.
and each time I clear and add Items my cache momory is always growing.
Can any one help me solving this Problem.

I've try to use GC.Collect but nothing happened.
I've tryed to nullify the hole page and also nothing happened.
also I've used EnableRowVirtualization="True" same thing nothing changed

Comment: What is the minimum code and markup someone could use to reproduce your issue? And what exactly is the issue you are seeing? As in I do x I see z in w. Your terminology is not immediately recognisable

Comment: Hi Andy,
the main problem is not in the Code after clearing the observable collection, and after leaving the software running for some time without doing anything the cache memory  is re-clean the Main Problem is how to Clear the cache directly after clearing the list or at least diminishing the time taken to clear the Heap Generation level 2 and the unmanaged memory .
Thanks for you care.